# Not able to fetch profile id from model as user in apex

Tags: apex

I have a trigger on provision object to create a user record when  provision record gets created on page layout i have a field called model if user select model user it should assign the profile from user  and assign it to new user  ...but it not assigning and toughing a error that profile id is empty when i am trying to to with query  it is working perfectly but i don't want to user query here . how can i avoid query here:

```
User M=[Select id,Name,ProfileId, from User where Id =: PR.Model__c];
PR.ProfileId = M.Profile Id///THis is working
```

i am trying to avoid a query and writing like this:

```
usr.ProfileId = PR.User__r.ProfileId; 
// it is not fetching the profile and thoughing and error saying profile id is missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access relationship fields in trigger, you can only access fields of the object that are in transaction.

So in your case, you will have to write a SOQL on User object to get the profileId or any other relationship fields.

Comment: Presume you meant "to get the profile Id"?

Comment: @KeithC Yup I meant `ProfileId`. Thanks for the observation, updated the answer